# Vectorize a loop where iterations are dependent on previous ones in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization, lapply, reduce

I have the following working code:

```
x <- c(10.7, 13.0, 11.4, 11.5, 12.5, 14.1, 14.8, 14.1, 12.6, 16.0, 11.7, 10.6,
       10.0, 11.4, 7.9, 9.5, 8.0, 11.8, 10.5, 11.2, 9.2, 10.1, 10.4, 10.5)

cusum <- function(x) {
  
  s <- NA
  mn <- mean(x)
  
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
  if (i == 1)
    s[i] <- 0 + x[i] - mn
  else
    s[i] <- s[i - 1] + x[i] - mn
  }
  
  s
  
}

cusum(x)
```

I wish to vectorize my code for performance, but I do not know how because:

- I can not use an "iterative dependency" (i.e. `s[i - 1]` to compute `s[i]`) in `lapply` and al.
- I can not loop over two vectors in `Reduce` (i.e. `s` and `x`)

How can I vectorize my function in base R? I work in a restrictive environment where I only have access to base R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need loops for this particular iteration: just use `cumsum` on `x - mean(x)`:

```
cumsum(x - mean(x))
 [1] -6.958333e-01  9.083333e-01  9.125000e-01  1.016667e+00  2.120833e+00  4.825000e+00  8.229167e+00  1.093333e+01  1.213750e+01
[10]  1.674167e+01  1.704583e+01  1.625000e+01  1.485417e+01  1.485833e+01  1.136250e+01  9.466667e+00  6.070833e+00  6.475000e+00
[19]  5.579167e+00  5.383333e+00  3.187500e+00  1.891667e+00  8.958333e-01 -1.598721e-14
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! I was so focus on `lapply`/`Reduce` and al. that i totally missed cumsum !

Answer (score 2):

@Cettt's answer is the most direct, and if that's what is needed, stick with it. However, if your point is that you don't know how to vectorize an arbitrary function, then ...

When your calculations rely on a value and the previous value, that's one thing, and vectorizing can be done. However, it looks as if your calculations rely on a previous calculation, in which case it's a different thing altogether. Your function appears to be the latter, so here's an attempt:

```r
func <- function(x) {
  mn <- mean(x)
  Reduce(function(a, b) {
    a + b - mn
  }, x, init = 0, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
}

func(x)
#  [1] -6.96e-01  9.08e-01  9.12e-01  1.02e+00  2.12e+00  4.82e+00  8.23e+00
#  [8]  1.09e+01  1.21e+01  1.67e+01  1.70e+01  1.62e+01  1.49e+01  1.49e+01
# [15]  1.14e+01  9.47e+00  6.07e+00  6.47e+00  5.58e+00  5.38e+00  3.19e+00
# [22]  1.89e+00  8.96e-01 -1.60e-14
```

Walk-through:

- `Reduce` first calls `func(x[1], x[2])`, let's call that result `res[1]`. It then calls `func(res[1], x[2])` (and stores in `res[2]`). Then `func(res[2], x[3])`, etc.
- Since you have a different first-condition (`if (i == 1)`), then we use `init=0` to seed that initial state. We could also have done something like:

  ```r
  func <- function(x) {
    mn <- mean(x)
    Reduce(function(a, b) {
      if (is.null(a)) {
        0 + b - mn
      } else {
        a + b - mn
      }
    }, x, init = NULL, accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
  }
  ```

  allowing for a more-complex initial condition.

  Since we defined `init=`, we also need to drop the first returned value in this case, ergo the `[-1]`.

3. `Reduce` defaults to only returning the last calculated value (`-1.60e-14` here), so we add `accumulate=TRUE` to capture all of the calculated values.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will indeed stick with @Cettt's answer, but your walk-through is very educational!